# Overlay legend on interactive ggvis plot

Tags: r, ggvis

I would like to put my legend inside the plot as [answered in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949540/ggvis-add-legend-with-multiple-data-and-position-legend-inside-graph), but for an interactive plot.

In the first code chunk the legend disappears off the plot, but when I remove the interaction it works.

```
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

# With drop down list it doesn't work
mtcars %>% 
  ggvis(x = ~wt, y = input_select(c("Miles per gallon" = "mpg", "Horse power" = "hp", "Displacement"="disp", "Carbohydrates" = "carb"), map = as.name, selected = "mpg", label = "Variables"), fill=~cyl) %>% 
  layer_points() %>% 
  add_relative_scales() %>%
  add_legend("fill", title = "Cylinders",
             properties = legend_props(
               legend = list(
                 x = scaled_value("x_rel", 0.8),
                 y = scaled_value("y_rel", 1)
               )))
```

[image]

```
# Remove interaction and it works
mtcars %>% 
  ggvis(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, fill = ~cyl) %>% 
  layer_points() %>% 
  add_relative_scales() %>%
  add_legend("fill", title = "Cylinders",
             properties = legend_props(
               legend = list(
                 x = scaled_value("x_rel", 0.8),
                 y = scaled_value("y_rel", 1)
               )))
```

[image]

How can I overlay the legend in an interactive plot?

Comment: With your first chunk of code, when I chose `Horse power`, the legend appeared. But it disappeared when I chose `Miles per gallon`. Since the value of y axis changes depending on users' choices, I wonder if there is something to do with this y-lim change. I somehow think that the legend position is set with the largest y value. `Horse power` has more than 300 whereas `Miles per gallon` has only 34. So by the time one chooses the latter, the legend disappears... This is just my speculation.

Comment: @jazzurro Interesting! Thank you for your speculation. Although, it seems to be arbitrarily every other selection. I added two more options to the drop down, If you choose `Horse power` and then choose `Displacement` and then choose `Miles per gallon` it appears.

Comment: This seems pretty buggy to me. I wonder if this issue is filed on github. It may be worth reporting this case.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is an open issue. Brief workaround I've found on https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/347 : add

```
%>% set_options(duration=0)
```

to the end of the plot:

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggvis(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, fill = ~cyl) %>% 
  layer_points() %>% 
  add_relative_scales() %>%
  add_legend("fill", title = "Cylinders",
         properties = legend_props(
           legend = list(
             x = scaled_value("x_rel", 0.8),
             y = scaled_value("y_rel", 1)
           ))) %>% set_options(duration=0)
```

It doesn't redraw the legend and that therefore doesn't disappear.